# VBA Excel - Paste to each Worksheet in a Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy a header from one workbook and paste it to each worksheet in a different workbook on the same range.

```
'header
Dim OP_wb As Workbook: Set OP_wb = ActiveWorkbook
Dim header As Range
Set header = OP_wb.Sheets("Optic Main").Range("A1:F1")

Dim Part_WS As Worksheet


Demand_WB.Activate

For Each Part_WS In Demand_WB
    header.Copy
    Demand_WB.Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Paste
Next Part_WS
```

I get this error:

> object doesn't support this property of method

on line:

```
For Each Part_WS In Demand_WB
```

Can someone help fix the code?

this is the code comes before my proble:

```
Dim Demand_WB As Workbook

Workbooks.Add


For i = 1 To 5

    Worksheets.Add

Next i

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\rosipov\Desktop\eliran\MFG - GSS\Demand_Optics " & Format(Now(), "dd.mm.yyyy") & ".xlsx"



Worksheets("Sheet1").Name = "Illuminators"
Worksheets("Sheet2").Name = "Analyzers"
Worksheets("Sheet3").Name = "Chuck"
Worksheets("Sheet4").Name = "Compensators"
Worksheets("Sheet5").Name = "Spectrometers"
Worksheets("Sheet6").Name = "LDSR"

Set Demand_WB = Workbooks("C:\Users\rosipov\Desktop\eliran\MFG - GSS\Demand_Optics " & Format(Now(), "dd.mm.yyyy") & ".xlsx")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For Each Part_WS In Demand_WB.Sheets
   header.Copy
   Part_WS.Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll 
Next Part_WS
```

Comment: Is the current error that shows up same as  the initial one (`object doesn't support this property of method`)?

Comment: You need to make sure that you assign `Demand_WB` to your target workbook. I expected it to be done outside the code block you originally showed. If not please do so. And do a `MsgBox(Demand_WB.Name)` to be sure it is showing the workbook name that you want the headers to be pasted to.

Comment: To assign to `Demand_WB` you would be doing something like `Set Demand_WB=Workbooks ("Demand.xlsx")`, assuming `Demand.xlsx` is already open.

Comment: I did this and occurs an error when I want to name the workbook. see my edited post.

Comment: And ofcourse remove the line. `Set Demand_WB = Workbooks("C:\Users\rosipov\Desktop\eliran\MFG - GSS\Demand_Optics " & Format(Now(), "dd.mm.yyyy") & ".xlsx")`

Comment: And also please do check before and inside `For` loop with `MsgBox` as mentioned in earlier comment. Just to be sure we are pasting in the right workbook.

Comment: And let me know which exact line is throwing error, so that we are on the same page. I might assume that the error is occuring at a different line than what you see.

Comment: now its is working! but, its copyng the header just to first sheet 6 times instead of moving to next sheet @bulbus

Comment: there are no errors right now, just not doing excatly what I wanted

Comment: That's because your code is still `ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Paste` and not what I posted as answer.

Comment: Please use `Part_WS.Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll`

Comment: Hey, it might be pasting to six sheets. Please go to each sheet and see that there are entries. The way we wrote the code is faster, does paste without going to the sheet.

Comment: Cheers Raphael have good day. The issue was that `Demand_WB=Workbooks(FullFileNamewPath)` doesn't work.

Comment: And that line was outside your original post, thus it took time.